# Unable to install pgAdmin III unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, software-center, 17.10, dependencies

I tried to install pgAdmin III for my ubuntu 17.10 without successful either via command line or software center:

`sudo apt-get install pgadmin3`

Resulted in

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 pgadmin3 : Depends: pgadmin3-data (= 1.22.2-1) but 1.22.2-2.pgdg17.04+1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Installing from software center, I got an error as screenshot below:

[image]

How do I check what is wrong and get pgAdmin III installed successfully? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I finally manage to solve my problem by using intelligent command `sudo aptitude install pgadmin3` instead of `sudo apt-get install pgadmin3`.

By using `sudo aptitude install pgadmin3`, it help suggested to remove unmet dependencies and downgrade any package as necessary and install pgadmin3 version as supported by system requirement.

And now I have my pgadmin III installed successfully, Thanks.